# Using Custom Function inside formula in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Details:

I have a sheet that has some formula that filters data based on another sheet part of the same spreadsheet.

Now I have a custom function that returns the name of the first sheet in the spreadsheet. I need to use this value inside the formula.

Formula

```
=IFERROR(SUM(filter('Sprint H 24102018-13112018'!E:E,'Sprint H 24102018-13112018'!B:B=A18,'Sprint H 24102018-13112018'!D:D=$B$1)),0)
```

Now I want to replace the name of the sheet (in single quotes) with the return value from my gScript function.

Function

```
function getFirstSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getName()
  Logger.log(sheet)
  return sheet;
  }
```

I tried the below but it gives a value of 0 with the single quotes and formula parse error without the single quotes.

Comment: As the return value of the function will be a string, did you try with NO quotes?

Comment: I did. It's giving formula parse error. I did mention that in the question

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet with editing rights?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a custom function inside a formula in Google Sheets, for example using INDIRECT in a QUERY:

```
=query(indirect("'"&getfirstsheet()&"'!B:E"),"select sum(E) where B ='"&A18&"' and D='"&$B$1&"' label sum(E) ''")
```

but it seems FILTER will not accept that construction.

Beware however that your function does not update for a change in sheet name.